# Way to define dynamic decorator in TS for long class without redefinition of all methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, es6-class

I have a class with pretty much of methods in it. Let's not focus here, that probably this class might be refactored and rewritten as several classes, because it will be eventually, but not know. I would like to have decorator, that decorates only one method of this class. We can do it in a several ways.

**Class interface:**

```
interface IFoo {
    method1 (): number;
    method2 (a: string): number;
    method3 (b: IFoo): number;
    method4 (c: string | (() => string)): number;
    method5 (d: number, e: string): number;
}
```

1. Classical OOP solution: define decorator which redefines particular methods, and just calling super implementation for all others. Something like this.

   ```
   class FooDecorator implements IFoo {
       constructor (
           private readonly provider: IFoo
       ) {}

       public method1 (): number {
           return this.provider.method1() + 1;
       }

       public method2 (a: string): number {
           return this.provider.method2.apply(this.provider, arguments);
       }

       public method3 (b: IFoo): number {
           return this.provider.method3.apply(this.provider, arguments);
       }

       public method4 (c: string | (() => string)): number {
           return this.provider.method4.apply(this.provider, arguments);
       }

       public method5 (d: number, e: string): number {
           return this.provider.method5.apply(this.provider, arguments);
       }
   }
   ```

   As you can see, pretty long writing and code duplication.
2. Try to utilize some JS capabilities.

   ```
   interface IFooDecorator {
       method1: IFoo["method1"];
   }

   class FooDecorator implements IFooDecorator {
       constructor (
           private readonly provider: IFoo
       ) {
           Object.setPrototypeOf(this, provider);
       }

       public method1 (): number {
           return this.provider.method1() + 1;
       }
   }
   ```

   Obvious downsides are wrong typization and usage of setPrototypeOf

I also tried to use Proxy, but there is poor support of typings with proxy usage as well. Does there any other solutions for that? The first approach is good, in case we can automate non decorated methods redefinition with `.apply` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the decorator as a factory function that uses `Object.create` instead of `class` syntax so that you won't need to use `Object.setPrototypeOf`:

```
function fooDecorator<T>(provider: IFoo): T implements IFoo {
    return Object.create(provider, {
        method1: {
            value(): number {
                return provider.method1() + 1;
            },
            writable: true,
            configurable: true
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Disclaimer: as you probably can see, I have no idea of TypeScript. Please suggest fixes by editing :-)

Comment: Well, even without typescript, idea is working. I was needed only to create additional method for strong types control. Thanks!